# using lambda to remove all a href tags with BeautifulSoup in a series of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

i have multi-column dataframe of Flickr tags with 41,000 rows, and in one of the column **i want to remove all the a href tags.** I find that BeautifulSoup is a superb package to parsing HTML documents.
But I find it hard to apply BeautifulSoup in only one column, leaving other columns intact, with as simple as possible python code.

this is my code for BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def remove_link(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    return soup.get_text()
```

my dataframe looks like this:

```
column1                              column2                                     column3
<a href="www.asia.com>Breda</a>      <a href="www.stackoverflow.com>result</a>   25,000
```

but i couldn't figure out yet how to apply this function with lambda, because i want the code as simple as possible.

I want to remove the **a href** tags only from column2, so the output should be like this:

```
column1                            column2    column3
<a href="www.asia.com>Breda</a>    result     25,000
```

Comment: `df['column2'] = df['column2'].apply(remove_link)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

apparently, it is as easy as this:

```
df['column2'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda x: remove_link(x))
```

I was confused about the remove_link(x) that's why i posted here. it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply.func` to refer to your function.

```
df['column2'] = df['column2'].apply(func = remove_link)
```